# Why doesn't OneDrive autostart or autosync?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

since I first used onedrive in windows 8.1 the sync engine skydrive.exe has never autostarted with windows or autosynced. It started only after I started the onedrive app `FileManager.exe` and synced only after I manually selected sync.

The progress page in the onedrive app always show "0 files remaining" regardless of what skydrive.exe is doing.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

### wsearch has to index it

it's because the wsearch service isn't indexing the onedrive folder. i had disabled wsearch on recommendation of samsung magician

> Indexing Service/Search
>
> This feature will be disabled because it requires a large number of random writes

by autostarting wsearch skydrive.exe autostart with windows

```
sc config wsearch start= delayed-auto
```

and by adding the onedrive folder to it in Indexing Options skydrive.exe autosync and the Progress page in the onedrive works and show f.e. "2 files remaining" or whatever skydrive.exe is doing

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL srchadmin.dll
```

### source

the only site i've seen that mention this crucial fact is http://www.rawinfopages.com/tips/2014/09/fix-microsoft-onedrive-sync-problems/. but it fails to point out that it's not enough for wsearch to be running, it also has to index the onedrive folder. another site say skydrive.exe automatically adds the onedrive folder to it when it's started. but i didn't see this happening